# Entity Core Explicit Loading With Many Sub Items

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

If have the following classes that are related to each other:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public List<ClassB> ClassBList { get; set; }
}
public class ClassB
{
    public ClassC ClassCItem { get; set; }
}
public class ClassC
{
    public List<ClassD> ClassDList { get; set; }
}
public class ClassD
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.0 and would like to use an object from Class A to explicitly load all the other objects. I tried this and it works:

```
context.Entry(classAObject).Collection(x => x.ClassBList)
                .Query()
                .Include(x => x.ClassCItem)
                .ThenInclude(y => y.ClassDList)
                .Load();
```

However, I would like the items in ClassDList to be ordered by the Index. How can this be done in a single call of Load()? If not, what would be the best way to retrieve all this information?

Comment: what's wrong with ordering it after you've fetched it from the DB?

Comment: my understanding of EF was that it won't necessarily insert and therefore later on retrieve in order if just based on Id. That's why I made an index to be able to retrieve it in the right order. But maybe that's not an issue?